# Getting response object in HttpSessionListener implementation class

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to alert user when session is about to expire. I don't want to use Ajax or JavaScript.
So how can I get a response object in  `sessionDestroyed()` method in `HttpSessionListener` implementation class so that I can send an `alert()` to current HTML page of user using response object.  Is there any way to do that?.

P.S: I want to avoid using Ajax or JavaScript calls.

Answer (score 2):

HTTP is stateless by nature. This is why sessions were created, but the container has no way of "pushing" info to the browser unless an open channel is there. This is why ajax/javascript have been used to bridge that gap.

In order to "push" anything to the browser you're going to need ajax.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot get the request from an `HttpSessionListener`. The reason is simple: session expiry events are independent of request events.

Additionally, since you want to alert when the session is *about* to expire, the `sessionDestroyed()` event is not good: it is called *after* the session has expired (actually destroyed, which may be even after it is expired).

Comment: Session *expiry* events are independent of request events.

Answer (score 0):

Since you specified no `AJAX`, you could take a look at [`WebSocket`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket):

> WebSocket is designed to be implemented in web browsers and web servers, but it can be used by any client or server application. The WebSocket Protocol is an independent TCP-based protocol. Its only relationship to HTTP is that its handshake is interpreted by HTTP servers as an Upgrade request. The WebSocket protocol makes possible more interaction between a browser and a web site, facilitating live content and the creation of real-time games. This is made possible by providing a **standardized way for the server to send content to the browser without being solicited by the client**, and allowing for messages to be passed back and forth while keeping the connection open. In this way a two-way (bi-directional) ongoing conversation can take place between a browser and the server. A similar effect has been achieved in non-standardized ways using stop-gap technologies such as Comet.

But for your problem, I'd stick with the traditional jQuery heartBeat client side, asking the server if the Session is not valid and then redirecting to the session-expired page.

Comment: I've found WebSockets to be unreliable. Some browsers have them disabled by default for example and they flat out don't work on Android.

Comment: Uh, thanks for sharing. It's the first time I hear that (but I'm not a daily user of WS, not at all...). Feel free to edit my answer to add more informations about your discoveries (opening a new question and answering yourself would be even better); I'd be interested in reading more

Answer (score 0):

Sessions expire when there are *no* requests during the entire timeout period, and therefore no responses either. Your question therefore doesn't actually make sense.